# Implementation of accumulator in open cv

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to add an array of image using " void accumulate(InputArray src, InputOutputArray dst, InputArray mask=noArray() ) ". Unfortunately, i did not able to do it. 
Does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The operation is called add():

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#add

The destination can be the source:

add(src, dst, dst, mask)